# Home page changed after magento update

Tags: products, home, column

I had a home page in my magento website that shows new products and a right column with specifiq widget.

But suddenly the home page shows nothing and the widget in right column is gone (I don't know exactly why but maybe because magento was updated to version 1.8)

Anyway I'm using this code in my magento home page

```
<!-- <reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
            <type>bundle</type>
            <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
            <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </block>
    <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="home.reports.product.viewed" alias="product_viewed" template="reports/home_product_viewed.phtml" after="product_new">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
            <type>bundle</type>
            <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
            <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </block>
    <block type="reports/product_compared" name="home.reports.product.compared" template="reports/home_product_compared.phtml" after="product_viewed">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
            <type>bundle</type>
            <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
            <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

-->

Thank you for helping

Comment: Magento 1.9 sets rws as package in the config.xml of some mage module. Maybe this is the problem, just go to the backend and make sure the right package/theme is chosen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento Admin Panel -> System -> Configuration -> Web -> Default Pages -> CMS Home Page -> Select the page you want as your home page and again check System -> Configuration -> Design -> Package & Theme (It must be your previous theme package)